# Python Escape Sequence and String Manipulation

Tags: python, string, escaping, sequence, backslash

I have the following two vars:

```
a = chr(92) + 'x11'
b = '\x11'
print 'a is: ' + a
print 'b is: ' + b
```

The result of these print statemtents:

```
a is: \x11
b is: <|        # Here I am just showing a representation of the symbol that is printed for b
```

How can I make it so that variable a prints the same thing as var b using the chr(92) call? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are showing you how to make `b` give you what you get in `a`.  If you want `a` to give you what you get in `b` (which is what you're asking, if I read you correctly), you need to decode the escape sequence:

```
>>> a
u'\\x11'
>>> a.decode('string-escape')
'\x11'
```

You can also use `unicode-escape` instead of `string-escape` if you want a unicode string as the result.

Comment: Yes they seem to be misinterpreting the question. I need to produce the same character using the chr(92). Is it possible to do that? Unfortunately I am away from my laptop so cant check your code.

Comment: @AasamTasaddaq: Check the code and if it doesn't do what you need then explain further.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation for [string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Backslash is an escape character in Python strings, so to include a literal backslash in your string you need to escape them by using two consecutive backslashes.  Alternatively, you can suppress the escaping behavior of backslashes by using a raw string literal, which is done by prefixing the string with `r`.  For example:

- Escaping the backslash:

  ```
  b = '\\x11'
  ```
- Using a raw string literal:

  ```
  b = r'\x11'
  ```

If I am misinterpreting your question and `b` should be `'\x11'` or equivalently `chr(17)`, but you just want it to display in the escaped format, you can use `repr()` for that:

```
>>> b = '\x11'
>>> print 'b is: ' + repr(b)
b is: '\x11'
```

If you don't want the quotes, use the [string_escape encoding](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings):

```
>>> print 'b is: ' + b.encode('string_escape')
b is: \x11
```

Or to get `a` to be the same as `b`, you can use `a.decode('string_escape')`.

Answer (score 0):

`\x11` appears to be the hex value for a `^Q` control character in ASCII:

```
\021  17  DC1  \x11  ^Q    (Device control 1) (XON) (Default UNIX    START char.)
```

You need to escape the `\` to get the literal `\x11`